# how to add a domain to receive email from without restarting mta

Tags: email-server

So i've been wondering that google apps adds a domain name to accept mail for that domain, but i am sure they would not go about restarting the mta to reload the settings every time. how do they manage adding a domain in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the domains in a database and let your MTA be configured dynamically from that database.

Comment: but even then, wont i have to reload the mta again, when there is a change in the database?

Comment: @Amit No you don't. At least I don't have to with my database driven configuration.

Comment: could u link me to a gist or smthng on how wud i go about doing so?

Comment: @Amit "could u link me to a gist or smthng on how wud i go about doing so?" Fo ReeLz?

Comment: @Amit I can't identify all your words in your sentence but the verb "to link" is known to me: http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze

Comment: @mailq thanx a lot! btw gist refers to gist.github.com

Comment: @Amit: in English (the official language of serverfault) gist means 'general meaning or understanding of a subject'.

Comment: i am a developer, and in my work environment gist refers to gist.github.com. and due to the frequent usage in that context i tend to forget, that it holds a diff meaning in english